# Will deadlifts build bicep muscles?

Tags: deadlifts, muscle-gain, biceps, powerlifting, compound-exercises

Will deadlifts build bicep muscles?

Comment: Do the arms bend? No? There's your answer.

Comment: Flagged for "very low quality". A simple google search would have given you the answer.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I already tried that, I found no results stated from reliable websites.

Comment: I think _this_ particular question is _too simple_, but I think it could perhaps be a much better question if it were along the lines of "Which compound-exercises / powerlifts focus on biceps?"

Comment: @RobSterach: You could tell us what your research brought up, why you didn't trust what you found and what your specific doubts were. Or tell us _why_ you'd want to know. Do you _want_ to build biceps and consider Deadlifts? Do you want to do Deadlift, but not overwork you biceps? All those informations would make for a nuanced, specific question. But right now it's a 5-word-question with a 1-word-answer and I don't feel like that lives up to community standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Will deadlifts build biceps?"*, **NO**, biceps won't develop/build by doing deadlifts, try curls instead.

Comment: (weighted) pull-ups are king :)